# Unable to load modules using Unity Framework

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I am trying to configure the unity framework in a app.config, can you please give an example of how to set this up please as when I am trying to do so using below app.config file I am getting below error:

> The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

My App.Config file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity>
    <containers>
      <container>
        <register  type="Interfaces.ICalculator, Interfaces"
                mapTo="CalculatorLibrary.Calculator,CalculatorLibrary"/>
        <register  type="Interfaces.ICalcRepLoop, Interfaces"
                mapTo="CalculatorLibrary.CalcRepLoop,CalculatorLibrary"/>
        <register  type="Interfaces.IConsoleInputService, Interfaces"
                mapTo="InputOutput.ConsoleInputService,InputOutput"/>
        <register  type="Interfaces.IConsoleOutputService, Interfaces"
                mapTo="InputOutput.ConsoleOutputService,InputOutput"/>
        <register  type="Interfaces.IInputParserService, Interfaces"
                mapTo="CalculatorCommandLibrary.InputParserService,CalculatorCommandLibrary"/>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

I am using dll from Prisim 4.0

Comment: Are your fully qualified names correct? The format is `Namespace.Subnamespace.ClassName, AssemblyName`. The assembly name is found in the Assembly Info area of the project properties.

Comment: What's the point to use config? Fluent API in C# is much easier.

Comment: SpikeX thanks for your response. I tried with fully qualified namespace as well but still getting same error.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164803/unity-error-the-given-assembly-name-or-codebase-was-invalid for investigation tips - mainly on using fusion log viewer.

Comment: Is container.LoadConfiguration() called at some point to load the config from the config file?